# How to pause a Jupyter notebook script until a button is pressed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget

I'm using the widget [notebook_login](https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/models-adding-libraries) that looks like this when run in a notebook:

```
notebook_login()
```

[image]

The problem is that it's in the middle of my notebook and if I click "run all", the next cells will run as well before I can press login. Is there a way to pause the notebook at this cell (where the widget is) until after I click "login"?

I found these several SO questions ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55244865/pause-jupyter-notebook-widgets-waiting-for-user-input), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629964/how-to-pause-jupyter-notebook-widgets-waiting-for-user-input)), but they seem to be very specific to their own unique buttons and I couldn't figure out a general way to do that (or more specifically to apply it to my situation)